# Cannot download PPA for Thinkpad Power Manager on 22.04

Tags: power-management, thinkpad, 22.04

I'm trying to install the Thinkpad Power Manager GUI on 22.04

I'm following this guide:

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/11/install-tlpui-in-ubuntu-or-linux-mint.html

but when I do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/apps
```

I get:

```
Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linuxuprising/apps/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
Reading package lists... Done                                  
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linuxuprising/apps/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What's the easiest way to get the power manager gui installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it clearly states "The PPA has TLPUI packages for Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 and 18.10 (and thus, Linux Mint 18 and 19 too)." so lacks support for 22.04/Jammy.

> What's the easiest way to get the power manager gui installed?

- Ask the maintainer for support for 22.04.
- Or use another PPA that has a current version. This one looks current: https://linrunner.de/tlp/index.html

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure that PPA contains TLPUI? It doesn't seem to find tlpui after I add that PPA and run `sudo apt install tlpui`